# Error: This Serverless Function has crashed

Tags: express, vercel

I can't deploy my server in vercel. I get this error every time. What should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAwKl.jpg)

Comment: Uhh, follow the instructions in the error to either make sure express is in  your package.json or manually install express on the server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.